# Crypto translate code from node js to java

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, licensing, signature

I want to check sign in offline mode:
I found the following code on node js

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const {
  KEYGEN_PUBLIC_KEY,
  LICENSE_KEY
} = process.env

// Extract key and signature from the license key payload
const [encodedKey, encodedSignature] = LICENSE_KEY.split('.')

// Decode the base64 encoded key
const key = Buffer.from(encodedKey, 'base64').toString()

// Verify the signature
const verifier = crypto.createVerify('sha256')
verifier.write(key)
verifier.end()

const ok = verifier.verify(KEYGEN_PUBLIC_KEY, encodedSignature, 'base64')
```

After that I tried to rewrite this code on java

```
byte[] publicBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sign.initVerify(pubKey);
byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println(sign.verify(decode));
```

But this doesn't work. The exception is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d`
Can anybody help me with this error?

Comment: Instead of using Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");, can you try with Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256");

Comment: In this case I go the following error java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256 Signature not available

Comment: You are calling `verify` before calling `update` (provide the message to be verified). Read the necessary steps 1-3 in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html

Comment: You are right Robert, it was the main problem here. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the following piece of code ?

```
byte[] publicBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
messageDigest.update(publicBytes);
byte[] outputDigest = messageDigest.digest();
```

After this, you can use your normal Base64 decode functionality.
You can refer below the example.
https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/how-to-create-sha256-rsa-signature-using-java.html